# Matrices of linear transformations - Rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

a)Define the matrix of linear transformation that maps any vector in $R^2$ to it's correspondent counter clockwise rotation of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ vector, and then find the matrix of that transformation in standard basis ($\gamma$) for $R^2$.

b)Find another matrix that represents the change of basis from standard basis to the basis: $\beta = \left\{ (1,2),(0,-2)\right\}$.

c)Find a the transformation $T_{\beta}^{\gamma}$, that is, the transformation $T(X)$ that starts in the basis $\gamma$ and ends in the basis $\beta$.

My answer:

a)$$
A =  \left[\begin{matrix}
cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) & -sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) \\
sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) & cos(\frac{\pi}{4})
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
Now the matrix of that transformation in standard basis:
$$
\gamma = \left\{(1,0),(0,1)\right\}\\
A\gamma_1 = A
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 \\
0
\end{matrix}\right] = 
\left[\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
0
\end{matrix}\right]
\\
A\gamma_2 = A
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 \\
0
\end{matrix}\right] = 
\left[\begin{matrix}
0\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{matrix}\right]
\\
T_{\gamma}^{\gamma} =
\left[\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0\\
0 & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\end{matrix}\right]
\\
$$

b)Matrix of change of basis, from $\gamma$ to $\beta$:
$$
(1,0) = a(1,2)+b(0,-2) \Rightarrow a = 1 , b = 1\\
(0,1) = a(1,2)+b(0,-2) \Rightarrow a = 0 , b = -\frac{1}{2}\\
I_{\beta}^{\gamma} = 
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -\frac{1}{2}
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

c)$$
T_{\beta}^{\gamma} = I_{\beta}^{\gamma}\cdot T_{\gamma}^{\gamma}\\
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -\frac{1}{2}
\end{matrix}\right] \cdot 
\left[\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0\\
0 & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\end{matrix}\right] =
\left[\begin{matrix}
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

I'm new to change of basis and linear transfromations... All I need in the moment is someone to check if my approach is good enough, and if everything I did is correct and makes sense... Thanks a lot!!

Comment: A counter clockwise rotation matrix by $\theta$ is of the form $$\left(\begin{matrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: But in the case for the standard basis, isn't correct what I've done?

Answer (score 1):

(a) In the standard basis, you can simply evaluate the cosines and sines in your matrix $A$:
$$T_\gamma^\gamma = \frac12\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt2 & -\sqrt2\\
\sqrt2 &  \sqrt2\end{bmatrix}.$$
Your method will give the same result if you multiply $A\gamma_1$ and $A\gamma_2$ correctly.

(b) Your calculations here are correct, but you accidentally filled in the matrix incorrectly.  The correct matrix is
$$I_\beta^\gamma = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
1 & -\frac12\end{bmatrix}.$$

(c)
$$\begin{align}
T_\beta^\gamma & = I_\beta^\gamma \cdot T_\gamma^\gamma\\\\
& = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0\\
 1 & -\frac12\end{bmatrix} \cdot 
 \frac12\begin{bmatrix}
 \sqrt2 & -\sqrt2\\
 \sqrt2 &  \sqrt2\end{bmatrix}\\\\
& = \frac14\begin{bmatrix}
 2 \sqrt2 & -2 \sqrt2\\
   \sqrt2 & -3 \sqrt2\end{bmatrix}.\end{align}$$